# Why does this error occur when using pool.map in Python with multiprocesssing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using the multiprocessing module in Python to render certain operations parallel. The function I want to parallelize is a method inside a class that I instantiate at a certain point in the program. The function returns an object of a class called History and doesn't take any arguments.

I want to use the map method of the Pool object in the multiprocessing module so I can create many different processes at the same time, I create a dummy list of numbers to take as "input" even though the method doesn't need it, and use:

Pool.map(function,numbers)

However this always raises the issue: History object is not callable.
Why does it say this? I want to return a lsit of history objects, why does it say I am trying to call them?

Code that calls method:

```
            p = Pool(process_count)
            numbers = [1] * process_count
            results = p.map(self.function(), numbers)
            p.join()
            p.close()
```

Comment: Please include rest of the relevant code.

Comment: With `self.function()` you call the function and give its return value to `p.map`. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pool.map` is a method which calls the supplied function on each of the element of the iterable parallel. When you supply `map` with `self.function()` as the first argument, you are not giving it a function but the *result* of the function - in your case `History`. Then `map` tries to call `History` resulting the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I remove the brackets () in the function name so that it can call the function instead of the object it returns, but it returns the following error: "KeyError: '__getstate__'". Do you know why it does this?

Comment: I would have to see the rest of the code. Anyway, create a new question if you can’t figure it out and could you mark my answer as accepted as it answers the original question.